# How to return nil in swift in a custom initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, convenience-methods

I am trying to write a custom initializer in swift. 
I have something like this:

```
convenience init(datasource:SomeProtocol) {
    assert(datasource != nil, "Invalid datasource")
    if(datasource == nil) {
        return nil
    }
    self.init()
}
```

The "return nil" line gives me this error: "could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments"

So, all I am trying to accomplish is to have this convenience initializer to return nil if the caller does not provide a valid datasource.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your program execution will not continue after the Assert. There is no reason to worry about the case that data source is nil afterwards

Comment: There is now a solution to this problem. You should consider changing your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `initializers` actually don't have return any value. You can't return `nil` if a method don't expect a return type.

To achieve what you are trying to do (i.e. force your class to have a datasource), just make your datasource **not** an optional. Variables that are not optional **must** have a value (so cannot be nil) and must be initialized.

Comment: This is no longer accurate as Swift now allows optional initializers.

Answer (score 51):

**Update:** Starting in Xcode 6.1 beta 1 [(available in the Mac Dev Center)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_683), Swift initializers can be declared to return an optional:

```
convenience init?(datasource:SomeProtocol) {
    if datasource == nil {
        return nil
    }
    self.init()
}
```

or an implicitly-unwrapped optional:

```
convenience init!(datasource:SomeProtocol) {
    if datasource == nil {
        return nil
    }
    self.init()
}
```

Comment: I think datasource type should be optional "SomeProtocol?"

Comment: @SuryavelTR: It was that way in the question; and it is not really relevant to the question, so I just left it. It was probably meant to be optional, but I guess it's theoretically possible (though highly unlikely) that `SomeProtocol` extends `NilLiteralConvertible` or something

Answer (score 13):

I think this would work, though it's not clear from your post where you are working with dataSource:

```
class func instOrNil(datasource:A) -> Self? {
    // do something with datasource
    if datasource.isValid() {
        return self()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Update Swift 3**

You can, of course, now return `nil` from an `init?(...)`:

```
init?(datasource: A){
    if datasource.isValid() {
        // initialise your properties from datasource
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You code works, but it's not efficient. You set the datasource has an optional (using **?**) and then validate if there is a datasource. If the parameter is not optional (remove the **?**), you will make sure that the value is not optional and you won't have to check if the datasource has a value. The use of **if let** is not useful in this case, because you don't need to unwrap the value (you don't use it anyway).

Comment: @Emilie you are correct. No need to make it optional then unwrap it. Changed the code.

Comment: is there a way to do it with an initializer instead of a class method?

Comment: As Emilie said earlier, init_xxx does not have a return type, so no, you can't return nil.

Answer (score 1):

If the superclass of this class is an Objective-C class, and you know that there's some input that will cause its initializer to return `nil`, you can simply pass that input to superclass's initializer, and that will cause your initializer to return `nil`:

```
import Foundation
class Foo : NSURL {
  convenience init(x: Int) {
    if x == 42 {
      self.init(string: "http://www.google.com/")
    } else {
      self.init(string: "not a url") // returns nil
    }
  }
}

let a: Foo? = Foo(x: 42)
println(a) // prints "Optional(http://www.google.com/)"
let b: Foo? = Foo(x: 17)
println(b) // prints "nil"
```

Of course, this only works if you're lucky enough to have a superclass whose initializer will return nil. So this is not a general solution.